# Why it is not reading num?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I don't know why I cannot read the num in EnrolList.js. I pass setStudentDetails from EnrolmentForm.js to App.js and from App.js will pass to EnrolList.js both the studentDetails and setStudentDetails. They are useState. Then they will display the details of the students. I am using fluentUI/react to display the student details. I am using useEffect to update the student details. I don't know the reason why, they cannot read num?
The App.js program

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import EnrolmentForm from './EnrolmentForm';
import EnrolList from './EnrolList';

function App() {
  const [ program, setProgram ] = React.useState("UG");
  const [ ugSeats, setUgSeats ] = React.useState(60);
  const [ pgSeats, setPgSeats ] = React.useState(40);
  const [ studentDetails, setStudentDetails ] = React.useState({})
  
  const handleChange = (event)=>{
    setProgram(event.target.value);
    setPgSeats(pgSeats);
    setUgSeats(ugSeats);
  }

  const setUpdatedSeats = (updatedSeats) => {
    if (program === "UG") {
      setUgSeats(updatedSeats);
    } else {
      setPgSeats(updatedSeats);
    }
    };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="programs">
        <h3 className="title">Student Enrolment Form</h3>
           <ul className="ulEnrol">
             <li className="parentLabels" onChange={handleChange}>
                 <input type="radio" value="UG" name="programGroup" defaultChecked/>
                 Undergraduate
                 <input type="radio" className="radioSel" value="PG" name="programGroup"/>
                 Postgraduate
            </li>
            <li>
              <label className="parentLabels">
                Remaining {program} Seats - {program === "UG" ? ugSeats: pgSeats}
              </label>
            </li>
           </ul>
      </div>
       <EnrolmentForm chosenProgram={program} setUpdatedSeats={setUpdatedSeats} currentSeats={program==='UG'?ugSeats:pgSeats} setStudentDetails={setStudentDetails} ></EnrolmentForm>
       <EnrolList setStudentDetails={()=>setStudentDetails} studentDetail={()=>studentDetails}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The EnrolmentForm.js program

```
import React from 'react';
import "./App.css";

function EnrolmentForm({chosenProgram, setUpdatedSeats, currentSeats,setStudentDetails}) {
  const [ firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState("");
  const [ lastName, setLastName ] = React.useState("")
  const [ email, setEmail ] = React.useState("");
  
  const handleClick = (event)=>{
    handleInputReset("","","")
    setUpdatedSeats(currentSeats-1);
    const randomKey = Math.floor(1000+Math.random()*9000);
    let id = randomKey ;
    setStudentDetails({
      num: id,
      fname: firstName,
      lname: lastName,
      program: chosenProgram,
      email: email,
    })
    console.log(id);
    event.preventDefault();
    
  }

  const handleInputChange = (setInput,event)=>{
    setInput(event.target.value);
  }

  const handleInputReset = (fname,lname,email)=>{
    setFirstName(fname);
    setLastName(lname);
    setEmail(email);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="enrolContainer">
        <form className="enrolForm" name="enrolForm">
          <ul className="ulEnrol">
            <li><label htmlFor="firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" className="inputFields" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value={firstName} onChange={(event)=>{handleInputChange(setFirstName,event)}}/>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label htmlFor="lastname">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" className="inputFields" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value={lastName} onChange={(event)=>handleInputChange(setLastName,event)} />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" className="inputFields" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value={email} onChange={(event)=>handleInputChange(setEmail,event)} />
            </li>
            <li id="center-btn">
               <input type="submit" id="btnEnrol" name="Enrol" alt="Enrol" value="Enrol" onClick={handleClick}/>  
            </li>
      </ul>
        </form>    
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default EnrolmentForm
```

The EnrolList.js program

```
import "./EnrolList.css";
import { DetailsList } from "@fluentui/react/lib/DetailsList";
import React from "react";

const columns = [
    
    {
    key: "fname",
    name: "First Name",
    fieldName: "fname",
    minWidth: 90,
    maxWidth: 200,
    isResizable: true,
    },
    {
        key: "lname",
        name: "Last Name",
        fieldName: "lname",
        minWidth: 90,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true,
    },
    {
        key: "program",
        name: "Program",
        fieldName: "program",
        minWidth: 60,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true,
    },
    {
        key: "email",
        name: "Email",
        fieldName: "email",
        minWidth: 130,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true,
    },
];

let items = [];

function EnrolList(props){
    
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        const curItemKey = props.studentDetails.num;
        if(curItemKey){
            items= [...items,props.studentDetails];
            props.setStudentDetails({});
        }
    },[props]);

    return (
        <div className="enrolList">
            <DetailsList items={items} columns={columns}/>
        </div>
    )
}    



export default EnrolList;
```

Cannot anyone tell me the reason why EnrolList.js:53  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'num')

I try to define the columns with num but still get the same result. Undefined.

Answer (score 0):

> Why it is not reading num?

You should really consider switching to ***typescript*** since you have several, really simple issues with data types.

1. `studentDetail={() => studentDetails}`

Your `EnrolList` component expects `studentDetails` prop (with `"s"` at the end) as an `object`, but you are passing it as a `function` that returns an `object`. It should be just `studentDetails={studentDetails}`.

2. `props.studentDetails.num;`

Initially, `studentDetails` is an empty `object`, so accessing `num` property will cause an error. You should secure this case and use e.g. *optional chaining* (`?`).

```
props.studentDetails?.num;
                // ^^^
```